# body.setTransform does not work inside contact listener (andEngine and box2d)

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I'm trying to move player body while contact with teleport but setTransform isn't executed.This is my contact listener

```
mPhysicsWorld.setContactListener(new ContactListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) 
        {

            final Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            final Body bodyA = fixtureA.getBody();

            final Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
            final Body bodyB = fixtureB.getBody();
            if(bodyA.getUserData().equals("Player") || bodyB.getUserData().equals("Player") )
            {

                for(int i = 0; i < telList.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(bodyA.getUserData() == telList.get(i))
                    {
                        Teleport tl = telList.get(i);
                        if(tl.look.getX() > pl.look.getX())
                        {
                            pl.moveTo(150, 320);
                            pl.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-4.5f,0));
                        }else
                        {
                            pl.moveTo(150, 320);
                            pl.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(4.5f,0));
                        }
                        break;
                    }else if(bodyB.getUserData() == telList.get(i))
                    {
                        Teleport tl = telList.get(i);
                        if(tl.look.getX() > pl.look.getX())
                        {
                            pl.moveTo(150, 320);
                            pl.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-4.5f,0));
                        }else
                        {
                            pl.moveTo(150, 320);
                            pl.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(4.5f,0));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) 
        {

        }
        });
```

Player class has method

```
public void moveTo(int x, int y)
{
    body.setTransform(new Vector2(x/32,y/32), 0);
}
```

and it works fine but isn't executed inside contact listener. And I'm sure contact is occured because it enters the "if" block and pl.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-4.5f,0)); is executed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why it's impossieble to use setTransform inside contact listener but I solved this problem in this way. Created class for tasks

public class moveBodyTask {

```
Player pl;
float x;
float y;
boolean direction;
moveBodyTask(Player b, float x1, float y1, boolean d)
{
    pl = b;
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    direction = d;
}

public void move()
{
    pl.moveTo(x, y);
    if(direction)
        pl.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(5,0));
    else
        pl.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-5,0));

}
```

}

then inside contack listener i just add new task to list

```
    taskList.add(new moveBodyTask(pl, x+TILE_SIZE, y, true));
```

and execute it while update

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            if(!taskList.isEmpty())
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < taskList.size(); i++)
                {
                    taskList.get(i).move();
                }
                taskList.clear();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

for me it works fine.

Comment: Although you did not know the reason, you provided the correct solution already: `setTransform()` is not working inside the contact listener because box2d's world is locked when the contact listener is executed. Therefore, you cannot move bodies manually, then. Adding the desired tasks to a list and executing them inside the update listener is the correct solution.

Comment: Marco, could you please tell me if this rule is the same for changing body type? For example from dynamic to static, do we need to do it on update as well? So far I have not experienced crashes, but wanted to be sure.